# How to refactor the entry point when retargeting a .NET Core ASP app to .NET 4.6.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to set up a project with ASP.NET MVC WebApi and an Angular 6 frontend. The project should target .NET 4.6.1 as I don't have cross platform requirements. Still, I want to use the .NET core project template as it has a couple of charasterics that I need for my development and deployment procedure:

- No explicit file management in VS, i.e. I don't need to add/remove files in VS. The project structure is identical to the file structure on the disc and updates in realtime
- A wwwroot directory which is used as app root by IIS by default
- A nice organisation of references, including npm packages

So far, I have set up the most part of it using the ASP.NET core project template from Visual Studio. I did the following:

1. Create the project from VS template
2. Changed target from `netcoreapp2.1` to `net461`
3. Removed the .NET core references and added the ASP.NET MVC assemblies

[image: References]

4. Removed all the startup classes which are .NET Core specific
5. Refactored my code (API controllers to .NET 4.6.1 classes, i.e. `IHttpActionResult` (.NET 4.6.1 instead of `ActionResult` (.NET core)

No, I need to rebuild the bootstrapping for the application and I'm stuck. I've created a global.asax file as in a normal ASP.NET application. When building, the compiler throws the error, that `Program.cs` doesn't contain a static `Main()` method as entry point (which makes sense, as I have deleted it in step 4).

Next, I've tried to create an entry point which launches the application defined in `global.asax.cs`:

```
public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      var application = new WebApiApplication();
      application.Init();
      Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

with global.asax.cs:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
}
```

The application compiles and runs. The browser is started. Then nothing happens.

My main question:

**How do I refactor the entry point of a .NET Core ASP project after changing the target to .NET 4.6.1?**

Am I on the right track with my approach? I am thankful for answers as well as links to resources which explain the topic.

and related:

Is it, given my requirements above, at all the correct way to retarget a .NET core app to .NET 4.6.1 to get the .NET core project structure and behavior in Visual Studio?

Comment: Why do you downvote without comment, please? Must be some really frustrated people around here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are very confused as to what is .NET Core and what is ASP.NET Core. .NET Core is a target framework while ASP.NET Core is a library. You are mixing ASP.NET Core with ASP.NET stuff which will never work since ASP.NET Core is not based on .NET Framework while ASP.NET is.

The idea of ASP.NET Core is that you can target .NET Core or .NET Framework as you see fit, without having to modify anything at all. In fact, targeting .NET Framework from an ASP.NET Core application is extremely easy:

1. Select the Web > ASP.NET Core Web Application project template.
2. Ensure .NET Framework is selected:

[image]

You can then choose the version of .NET Framework you want in the project options as always.

Furthermore, should you decide that you want to support both .NET Core and .NET Framework, it is just as easy as editing the csproj to include both targets:

1. Remove the `<TargetFramework>` attribute:

   ```
   <TargetFramework>net471</TargetFramework>
   ```
2. Add the `<TargetFrameworks>` attribute:

   ```
   <TargetFrameworks>net471;netcoreapp2.0</TargetFrameworks>
   ```

Comment: Thank you! Don't know where I got lost there on the way.